# Writing to new workbook instead of sheet in existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert this code from writing to sheet 2 of the same excel workbook to create another workbook called destin.xls and dump all the information there.

Any suggestions?

```
Sub test()
s1 = "Sheet1"
s2 = "Sheet2"
Set r = Sheets(s1).Range(Sheets(s1).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(s1).Cells(Sheets(s1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, 1)) 
Count = 1
For Each c In r
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 1) = "" & c.Value & ""
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 2) = "" & Sheets(s1).Cells(Count + 1, 2).Value & ""
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 3) = "animals/type/" & c.Value & "/option/an_" & c.Value & "_co.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 4) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/option/an_" & c.Value & "_co2.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 5) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/shade/an_" & c.Value & "_shade.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 6) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/shade/an_" & c.Value & "_shade2.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 7) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/shade/an_" & c.Value & "_shade.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 8) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/shade/an_" & c.Value & "_shade2.png"
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 9) = "" & Sheets(s1).Cells(Count + 1, 3).Value & ""
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 10) = "" & Sheets(s1).Cells(Count + 1, 4).Value & ""
    Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 11) = "" & Sheets(s1).Cells(Count + 1, 5).Value & ""
    Count = Count + 1
Next c

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the data into an array, then create a new sheet, output the array and use .Move to move the added sheet to its own workbook, and then save the ActiveWorkook as whatever name you want, like so:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim arrResults() As Variant
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If rngData.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub    'No data

    ReDim arrResults(1 To rngData.Rows.Count, 1 To 11)
    strFolderPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    For Each DataCell In rngData.Cells
        ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
        Select Case (Len(ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text) > 0)
            Case True:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text & ""
            Case Else:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 1) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "A").Text & ""
        End Select
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 2) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "B").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 3) = "animals/type/" & DataCell.Text & "/option/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_co.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 4) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/option/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_co2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 5) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 6) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 7) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 8) = "animals/" & DataCell.Text & "/shade/an_" & DataCell.Text & "_shade2.png"
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 9) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "C").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 10) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "D").Text & ""
        arrResults(ResultIndex, 11) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "E").Text & ""
    Next DataCell

    'Add a new sheet
    With Sheets.Add
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Copy .Range("A1")
        .Range("A2").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(arrResults, 2)).Value = arrResults
        '.UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit   'Uncomment this line if desired

        'The .Move will move this sheet to its own workook
        .Move

        'Save the workbook, turning off DisplayAlerts will suppress prompt to override existing file
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strFolderPath & "destin.xls", xlExcel8
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rngData = Nothing
    Set DataCell = Nothing
    Erase arrResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Tigeravatar this is amazing and it works great! thank you! I have one question. For the newly created document i want to add headers to it, so how do i add the following:                     book.Sheets(s2).Cells(1 , 1) = "Header 1"
book.Sheets(s2).Cells(1 , 2) = "Header 2"
book.Sheets(s2).Cells(1 , 3) = "Header 3"
book.Sheets(s2).Cells(1 , 4) = "Header 4"

Comment: see above comment. Thanks

Comment: If you have the headers in Sheet2 already (which I assumed), then getting the headers is what this line was for: `Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Copy .Range("A1")`  However, if you need to add the headers manually in code, you would use a line like this instead: `.Range("A1").Resize(, 11).Value = Array("Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3", etc...)`

Comment: actually i think that will be fine reading from sheet 2, thanks :)

Comment: One last thing. In the source file i have two columns and i want to create an if statement that says --> If column A is there( meaning numbers were entered), but column B is blank, then display Column A value  else  if Column A is there and Column B is there then display Column B's value.....i want to do this row by row. Does it make sense?

Comment: For some reason all though i have a value in Column B and A, but its still taking value A.......I forgot to mention that Column B's values are static "422rf3" while Column A's values are all different or unique

Comment: Worked fine for me when I tested it.  I'd have to see an example where it's not working.

Comment: i have bunch of values in column E and its rows and "422rf3" in Column F, but not in all rows ( some are blank) because i want that if both Column E and F have the values in it i want to take the value of whatever is in that Column E row and display it in column K of the new excel sheet that im creating. If a particualr row is blank in Column F that i want to take the value that is in column E's row

Comment: Column K is column 11, adjust the code so that you are checking on 11 instead of 1.

Comment: No dice :( --> This is what i did                                          For Each DataCell In rngData.Cells
        ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
        Select Case (Len(ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "F").Text) > 0)
            Case True:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 11) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "F").Text & ""
            Case Else:  arrResults(ResultIndex, 11) = "" & ws.Cells(DataCell.Row, "E").Text & ""
        End Select

Comment: Sorry, but here's some clarity in to my logic: In the source file:         If E and F has values, then i want to take F value                            If E is blank i want to take F value                                       If F is blank i want to take E value

Comment: I want the final value to only display in column k of the new document workbook

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to try something like this:

```
Dim orig As Workbook
Set orig = ActiveWorkbook

Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Add

...
Set r = orig.Sheets(s1).Range(...)
...
book.Sheets(s2).Cells(...) = orig.Sheets(s1).Cells(...)
...

book.SaveAs("destin.xls")
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for replying. I did what you said, but for some reason it creates the document, but kept saying that it already exist when it doesnt and it doesnt put the entries from the source excel file. Here is what i did

Comment: Sub test()
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Add
    s1 = "Sheet1"
    s2 = "Sheet2"
    Set r = Sheets(s1).Range(Sheets(s1).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(s1).Cells(Sheets(s1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row, 1))
    
    Count = 1
    For Each c In r
        book.Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 1) = "" & c.Value & ""
        book.Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 2) = "" & Sheets(s1).Cells(Count + 1, 2).Value & ""
        book.Sheets(s2).Cells(Count + 1, 3) = "animals/" & c.Value & "/option/an_" & c.Value & "_co.png"
        Count = Count + 1

book.SaveAs ("destin.xlsx")
    Next c
    
End Sub

Comment: @Chuck I made an edit to this answer where the original workbook is saved into an `orig` variable.  This is necessary because otherwise the calls to `Sheets` will be looking for sheets in the new workbook instead of the original one.  See if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this (excuse any incorrect syntax I don't have excel to hand, but you get the idea) ...

```
Sub SourceToDest()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    ' Setup Source
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Setup Dest
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Now just copy your values from the wsSource to the wsDest
    wsDest.Cells(Count + 1, 1) = "" & c.Value & ""
    'etc... as you where doing...

    'or copy directly from one sheet to another...
    wsDest.Cells(Count + 1, 1) = wsSource.Cells(Count + 1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: oh yeah.... don't forget to save it, as Rob I mentions in his example (must have added that I was writing my example... much the same sort of thing)

Comment: Hi Code_fodder, thanks for replying. I tried that and for some reason it will not run

Comment: Which part did not work? (it was not tested for syntax, I am using linux at work at the moment...so only use libra office at the moment, I can take a look over the weekend.)